# add_n() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)

Tags: tensorflow

This is my first code with tensor flow.

If I split the addition it works, but I am sure there's a way to add N tensors in one line.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Create a graph.
g = tf.Graph()

# Establish the graph as the "default" graph.
with g.as_default():
  # Assemble a graph consisting of the following three operations:
  #   * Two tf.constant operations to create the operands.
  #   * One tf.add operation to add the two operands.
  x = tf.constant(8, name="x_const")
  y = tf.constant(5, name="y_const")
  z = tf.constant(4, name="z_const")
  my_sum = tf.add_n(x, y, z, name="z_y_x_sum")

  # Now create a session.
  # The session will run the default graph.
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    print my_sum.eval()
```

Can you help me to figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the tensors into a list:

```
my_sum = tf.add_n([x, y, z], name="z_y_x_sum")
```